# MySQL query to get two value useing Between

Tags: mysql

I need to select data from a mysql database. I submit value from 'FORM' `VENUE=10000003`, `START_DATE=1452673900` and `END_DATE=1452663000`.

In database there exists `startDate=1452673800` and `endDate=1452663000` and `venue=10000003`

But I can't results by this query

```
SELECT * FROM `training_calendar` WHERE `venue`='10000003' AND `startDate` BETWEEN (1452673800 AND 1452663000)
AND `endDate` BETWEEN (1452673800 AND 1452663000)
```

Help Please

Comment: You should be seeing a syntax error, telling you to check the manual—which makes crystal clear that the minimum and maximum operands of [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) should not be enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change places of values, lowest date must be first in `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM `training_calendar` 
WHERE `venue`='10000003' AND `startDate` BETWEEN 1452663000 AND 1452673800
AND `endDate` BETWEEN 1452663000 AND 1452673800
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand it right, but try this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM training_calendar WHERE venue='10000003' AND startDate BETWEEN            
1452663000 AND 1452673800 OR endDate BETWEEN 1452663000 AND 1452673800
```

If you already have an exactly startDate and endDate why don't you just search for those exactly values like:

```
SELECT * FROM training_calendar WHERE venue='10000003' AND startDate >   
1452673800 AND endDate < 1452663000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT CASE,

```
select 
case when startDate between '1452663000' and '1452673800' then startDate as   'startDate'
case when enddate between '1452663000'and '1452673800' then endDate as 'endDate'
from 'training_calendar where venue='10000003';
```